# Stop multiprocessing thread from another module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, terminate

I want to kick off an infinite loop in a multiprocess in module B from module A. At a later point, I want to terminate the multiprocess from module A as well.

The problem I am having is that if I try to save a boolean like `keep_running` in B, it keeps getting reset, even when I tried using `global`.  I have read that `global` is best avoided.

#### A

```
import multiprocessing

keep_running = True

def stop_it(conf):
   global keep_running
   keep_running = False

def start_it(arg):
   while keep_running:
       do_stuff(arg)
       time.sleep(1)

def main(args):
   ...
   configs.configuartions.Configurations()
   configs.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_it, args=(arg,))
   configs.process.start()

if __name__ == 'main':
   import sys
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

#### B

```
import A.main as m


def on_init(<args>):
   m.main([conf_file, database])

def on_stop(conf):
   m.stop_it(conf)
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: a thread is something different than a process. Also, you should give an reproducible example, that we can run without any hassles.

Comment: Is the sleep(1) call part of the workflow, or is it just there to wait and see if the job is interrupted? And do you have a clear preference for multiprocessing instead of threading? Threading can multitask when one thread is sleeping (like your example) but multiprocessing works better if both processes need to work intensively. Anyway, you might take a look at the Event class in either library. It lets code in one thread/process alert another one when an event occurs. This is necessary because the two parts of A will be be running in different threads/processes.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp - the sleep is to give space between requests.  In the end, I used Roman's idea of using pids.  I didn't have a preference one way over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using multiprocessing, you have created separate processes that cannot access each other's variables. In such case you have to communicate through pipes, signals, sockets or flag files.

To be able to access each other variables, you would use threading instead of multiprocessing. However, you can still kill a different process using `os.kill` by sending a `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` to it. You would need PID for this, you can get it as `configs.process.pid` in your example.

More information is in official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html